# Ratio test for complicated functions

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, ratio

I am trying to determine the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-1^{n}*(n)^2*(x+2)^n}{3^n}$. When I do the ratio test I get the limit of $\frac{(-1)*(x+2)}{3}$, or $\frac{-1}{3}*|x+2| < 1$, however the answer is that the radius of convergence is p = 3. Did I incorrectly compute the limit? Any guidance would be very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems.  When you say $\frac{-1}{3}*|x+2| < 1$, this is true for any $x$ as the left side is negative.  If you are taking absolute values you should include the $-1$ in the absolute value, which means you can ignore it.  Now you have $\frac{1}{3}*|x+2| < 1, |x+2| \lt 3, x \in (-5,1)$ and the radius of convergence is indeed $3$.  The interval is centered on $-2$.

Comment: Thanks! If $|x+2| < 3 for x $\in$ (-5, 1) does this mean that we take the length of the interval excluding the endpoints and divide this by 2 to get the radius?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  The length of the interval does not depend on whether it includes the endpoints.  Here since the comparison is $\lt$ you should not include them.

Comment: Great, thanks. So if I had for example -4 < |x| < -2 then the interval would be (-4, -2) and the radius would be 1?

Comment: It would if you didn't have the absolute value signs on $x$.  As written, there is no $x$ that satisfies the inequalities.